# Plot times series multiple line x axis as date

Tags: r, date, plot, time-series

I know it might be an old repeated question but I searched all the possible pages and could not find an appropriate answer. I have a time series data like below. I want to plot it as x-axis as time (just year or both month and year) and the rest of the columns as y (all in one plot). I tried different functions such as plot, ggplot(2), ts.plot, plot.ts and none of them gives me what I need. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

you need to create a date field. See the sample below, it has some dummy values code which you can ignore. You can use the date part (I use lubridate), and ggplot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

mp$date <- ymd(paste(mp$year,'-',mp$month,'-','01',sep = ""))
mp$Uymax <- rnorm(48,4555,54)
mp$Uymin<- rnorm(48,5656,34)
mp$uymedian<- rnorm(48,6767,43)
mp$uy90<- rnorm(48,7676,56)
mp$uy10<- rnorm(48,7676,66)

library(tidyverse)
mp$date <- ymd(paste(mp$year,'-',mp$month,'-','01',sep = ""))

mp %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(date,Uymax,color='Uymax')) +
  geom_line(aes(date,Uymin,color='Uymin')) +
  geom_line(aes(date,uymedian,color='uymedian')) +
  geom_line(aes(date,uy90,color='uy90')) +
  geom_line(aes(date,uy10,color='uy10'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Aji. It worked. I also did a minor change to it. Since in your code, the y lable is set autumatically based on the first line, Uymax (which might not what desired), I chaned the first line to ggplot(mp, aes(Date,mp)). So, the y lab is now mp or can be changed to any other desired name.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest to transform your data from wide-format to long-format in order to graph multiple variables in one plot. Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/) that would help you with that.

Here's an example that mimics your code

```
library(reshape2); library(ggplot2)


df <- data.frame(Month = 1:11, Year = 2000: 2010, UY_Min = 1:11, UY_Media = 20:30, UY_90Per = 30:40)

df_long <- melt(df, id.vars = c("Month", "Year"), variable.name = "UY", value.name = 
   "Values") #convert the table from wide to long format. you can name variable.name and value.name appropriately
```

here, I'm using a line plot as an example, but really once you shape your data to long-format, you can use any geom function you desire. then dress it up as necessary.

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(Year, The_Values, col = UY)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2000, 2010, by = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: @Thanks Wally Ali. I had tried this before. The graph is not as appropriate as I need.